# R - Finding and combining multiple character columns

Tags: r, character, multiple-columns, dummy-variable

In short, I kind of want to do the reverse process of `model.matrix()`. I have the following data obtained from a survey.

Question 1: pick one from 'Cat', 'Dog' or 'Sheep'
Question 2: pick a random number
Question 3: pick one from 'Big' or 'Small'

The results are put in a dataframe in the following way:

```
    id   ans_1   ans_2   ans_3   num    size_1   size_2
    1    Cat     0       0       0.76   0        Small 
    2    0       Dog     0       0.44   0        Small 
    3    0       0       Sheep   0.52   Big      0     
    4    0       0       Sheep   0.52   Big      0     
    5    0       Dog     0       0.59   0        Small 
    6    Cat     0       0       0.97   0        Small 
    7    0       Dog     0       0.5    0        Small 
    8    0       Dog     0       0.19   0        Small 
    9    0       0       Sheep   0.01   Big      0     
   10    Cat     0       0       0.24   0        Small
```

What I want to do is to combine the answers of every question in a single column.  In this example, ans_1, ans_2 and ans_3 are from the same question and size_1 and size_2 as well. Combining them, the results would look like:

```
   id    ans     num    size  
    1    Cat     0.76   Small        
    2    Dog     0.44   Small        
    3    Sheep   0.52   Big          
    4    Sheep   0.52   Big          
    5    Dog     0.59   Small        
    6    Cat     0.97   Small        
    7    Dog     0.5    Small        
    8    Dog     0.19   Small       
    9    Sheep   0.01   Big         
   10    Cat     0.24   Small
```

I have multiple datasets, each of which contains around 100 columns. This makes it too much work to do by hand. Note that there are also columns like 'num', which stand by themselves. The answers to the same question are always right next to each other like in this example.

Thank you!

**Data**

```
id = 1:10
ans_1 = c('Cat', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Cat', 0, 0, 0, 'Cat')
ans_2 = c(0, 'Dog', 0, 0, 'Dog', 0, 'Dog', 'Dog', 0, 0)
ans_3 = c(0, 0, 'Sheep', 'Sheep', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Sheep', 0)
num = round(runif(10),2)
size_1 = c(0, 0, 'Big', 'Big', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Big', 0)
size_2 = c('Small', 'Small', 0, 0, 'Small', 'Small', 'Small', 'Small', 0, 
'Small')

data <- noquote(cbind(id, ans_1, ans_2, ans_3, num, size_1, size_2))
```

Comment: `cbind` is returning a matrix, not a data.frame. Just use `data.frame`.

Comment: One option to clean it up: `library(tidyverse); data %>% unclass() %>% as_data_frame() %>% mutate_all(na_if, '0') %>% type_convert() %>% mutate(ans = coalesce(ans_1, ans_2, ans_3), size = coalesce(size_1, size_2)) %>% select(-matches('_\\d+$'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to use `unite()` from tidyr, and then `mutate_if()` from dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

data <- data_frame(id, ans_1, ans_2, ans_3, num, size_1, size_2)

data %>% 
    unite(ans, ans_1, ans_2, ans_3) %>% 
    unite(size, size_1, size_2) %>%
    mutate_if(is.character, str_extract, "[a-zA-Z]+")

#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>       id   ans   num  size
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1      1   Cat  0.92 Small
#> 2      2   Dog  0.79 Small
#> 3      3 Sheep  0.44   Big
#> 4      4 Sheep  0.67   Big
#> 5      5   Dog  0.00 Small
#> 6      6   Cat  0.61 Small
#> 7      7   Dog  0.67 Small
#> 8      8   Dog  0.95 Small
#> 9      9 Sheep  0.18   Big
#> 10    10   Cat  0.76 Small
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with matrix subsetting and `max.col` like this.

```
dataNew <- data.frame(id=data$id,
                     ans=data[,2:4][cbind(seq_along(data$id), max.col(data[, 2:4] != "0"))],
                     num=data$num,
                     size=data[,6:7][cbind(seq_along(data$id), max.col(data[, 6:7] != "0"))],
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The third variable, num is created by subsetting to variables 2:4 and then using matrix subsetting to return elements in each row that correspond to the desired output. In this case, `seq_along` returns the set of rows and `max.col` is used to find the variable within each row that is not 0.

**data**

```
data <- 
structure(list(id = 1:10, ans_1 = c("Cat", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"Cat", "0", "0", "0", "Cat"), ans_2 = c("0", "Dog", "0", "0", 
"Dog", "0", "Dog", "Dog", "0", "0"), ans_3 = c("0", "0", "Sheep", 
"Sheep", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Sheep", "0"), num = c(0.44, 0.36, 
0.2, 0.72, 0.98, 0.94, 0.52, 0.84, 0.34, 0.04), size_1 = c("0", 
"0", "Big", "Big", "0", "0", "0", "0", "Big", "0"), size_2 = c("Small", 
"Small", "0", "0", "Small", "Small", "Small", "Small", "0", "Small"
)), .Names = c("id", "ans_1", "ans_2", "ans_3", "num", "size_1", 
"size_2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, a data.frame would probably be more suitable ..

```
ans<-apply(data[,2:4],1,function(x) x[x!="0"])
(data.new<-cbind(id=data[,1],ans,data[,5:7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a function over selected fields (`data[, grep('ans', colnames(data))]` or `data[, c('ans1', 'ans2', 'ans3')]`) and ask or non - 0 values

```
ans <- apply(data[, grep('ans', colnames(data))], 1, function(x) x[x!=0])
size <- apply(data[, grep('size', colnames(data))], 1, function(x) x[x!=0])

data2 <- data.frame(id, ans, num, size)

> data2
   id   ans  num  size
1   1   Cat 0.79 Small
2   2   Dog 0.66 Small
3   3 Sheep 0.77   Big
4   4 Sheep 0.63   Big
5   5   Dog 0.48 Small
6   6   Cat 0.06 Small
7   7   Dog 0.63 Small
8   8   Dog 0.59 Small
9   9 Sheep 0.24   Big
10 10   Cat 0.96 Small
```